# Scalar products on symmetric functions behaving like the Macdonald scalar product

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics

The Macdonald symmetric functions (or Macdonald polynomials)
$P_\lambda(x)$ are orthogonal with respect to the Macdonald scalar
product
$$ \langle p_\lambda,p_\mu\rangle =
    \delta_{\lambda\mu}z_\lambda\prod_{i=1}^{\ell(\lambda)}
     \frac{1-q^{\lambda_i}}{1-t^{\lambda_i}}. $$
I am using standard symmetric function notation as found in Macdonald,
*Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials*, second ed. The
$P_\lambda(x)$'s  are uniquely determined by this orthogonality and by
the triangularity condition
$$ P_\lambda(x) = m_\lambda(x)
  +\sum_{\mu<_L\lambda}u_{\lambda\mu}m_\mu(x),\ (*) $$
where $<_L$ denotes lexicographic order on partitions of $n$
(with $\langle 1^n\rangle$ first and $(n)$ last). It is a nontrivial
fact that (*) continues to hold if $<_L$ is replaced by dominance
order $<$. (See the remark on page 323 of Macdonald's book.) What is
the most general scalar
product with this property? Does it have to coincide with the
Macdonald scalar product or some limits thereof (such as the Jack
scalar product, where we replace
$\frac{1-q^{\lambda_i}}{1-t^{\lambda_i}}$ with $\alpha^{\ell(\lambda)}$)?

Another viewpoint is obtained by defining
$$ \langle p_\lambda,p_\mu\rangle = \delta_{\lambda\mu} y_\lambda,
   $$
where $y_\lambda$ is an indeterminate. If we restrict to partitions of
$n$, then the condition that triangularity with respect to $<_L$
implies triangularity with respect to $<$ defines an algebraic
variety. What is the structure of this variety?